# Design pattern to support different screen on UIViewControllerRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the general pattern for supporting a different display on a VC rotation?

Would I create a new VC in interface builder, design it, etc.. Then on willRotate, segue to it? Or what is the proper way to handle this?

Example, tableview in portrait.
Rotate left, and now show a graph

Comment: The most common pattern is to change the layout of the _current_ view.  That is, to not transition to a new vc on rotation.

Comment: If you really want to completely different views like a table and a graph, then it probably would be best to have a separate view controller for each orientation. However, I wonder if this will violate Apple's Human Interface Guidelines -- a user would expect the same view, with maybe a different layout on rotation, but a totally new view? I don't know .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eneded up adding a different view controller designed sideways. Then I used the rotation delegate methods to figure out when something rotates to make the move.